# Remote API JAVA url does not work GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have deployed application into GAE. When i try the url as http://aabbbaaacccc.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api. I am getting 404 Error page. I have added in web.xml file. I have given correct app id. It deploys. After deployment successful, An dialog box appears and displays file not found along with notepad.

```
<servlet>
<display-name>Remote API Servlet</display-name>
<servlet-name>RemoteApiServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>RemoteApiServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/remote_api</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I need to deploy my app into server and start a Remote api with an other application and share the entites from an other app.

I am struggling with this issue for past 2 days. Please help me.

U can look at the error dialog box in the following link.

http://i40.tinypic.com/bfgzki.png

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appengine should works fine.. i've listed the all details for basic project setup. please look and find what you missed.

**The Servlet Class**

App Engine Java applications use the Java Servlet API to interact with the web server. 
In the directory src/guestbook/, make a file named GuestbookServlet.java with the following contents:

```
package guestbook;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class GuestbookServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world");
    }
}
```

**The web.xml File**

When the web server receives a request, it determines which servlet class to call using a configuration file known as the "web application deployment descriptor." This file is named web.xml, and resides in the war/WEB-INF/ directory in the WAR. WEB-INF/ and web.xml are part of the servlet specification.

In the directory war/WEB-INF/, a file named web.xml has the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Oracle Corporation//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>guestbook</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>guestbook.GuestbookServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>guestbook</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/guestbook</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

This web.xml file declares a servlet named guestbook, and maps it to the URL path /guestbook.

**The appengine-web.xml File**

App Engine needs one additional configuration file to figure out how to deploy and run the application. This file is named appengine-web.xml, and resides in WEB-INF/ alongside web.xml.

In the directory war/WEB-INF/, a file named appengine-web.xml has the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application></application>
    <version>1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
```

appengine-web.xml is specific to App Engine, and is not part of the servlet standard. You can find XML schema files describing the format of this file in the SDK, in the appengine-java-sdk/docs/ directory. See Configuring an App for more information about this file.

**Running the Project**

The App Engine SDK includes a web server application you can use to test your application.

select `Debug As > Web Application`.

**Testing the Application**

Start the server, then visit the server's URL in your browser. If you're using Eclipse and the Google Eclipse plugin, the server runs using port 8888 by default:

```
http://localhost:8888/guestbook
```

If you're using the dev_appserver command to start the server, the default port is 8080:
For details please see following tutorials:

[Tutorial 1:](http://www.vogella.com/articles/GoogleAppEngineJava/article.html)

[Tutorial 2:](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating)

[Tutorial 3:](http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-app-engine-hello-world-example-using-eclipse/)

Comment: you have the 8888 ports in used by another application or your app engine development server is already working.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-java/OlMPFx-lJek

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. I need one more help from you. Can u please guide me how to add remote api to copy data entities from one application to an other. abcdefgh.appspot.com/_ah/_remote_api.

Comment: Well dear.. Its not discussion forum for idea.. I'm not able to get you clearly.. Its better to post question at stackoverflow.. If you have some specific problem....
For data storage you can see following:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/storage

Comment: I am trying to copy entities from one app to another app in GAE. I need to have Remote api configurations to copy entities. So How to configure Remote API for java application in web.xml.